In Pycharm is there a way to subprocess an executable and capture the output, as if you have Emulated Terminal enabled?
Solution:
I didn't realise I could run subprocesses detached.
This is my solution which allows you to use the standard pycharm console with debug, and access to unusual/blocked stdout/stderr subprocesses:
def run_commands_detached(cmds: list[str]) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    """
    The pycharm debugger cannot be used at the same time as the terminal is emulated.
    This function runs cmds in a seperated console which allows returning of the stdout & stderr
    """
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS  # Windows
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmds,
                               creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                               startupinfo=startupinfo,
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    stdout, stderr = stdout.decode("utf-8"), stderr.decode("utf-8")
    return stdout, stderr

